# Downloading a csv file in target folder and renaming it

Tags: java, excel, file-rename

I have been trying to download a file in a target folder and rename it. This should be automatically done. Is this possible?
If yes, how should the code be written in Java?

Comment: What have you tried so far.Post your code

Comment: First download file as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/921400/6743203. After downloading you will know how to rename it

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure where you are trying to download from but as mentioned this my help: [stackoverflow.com/a/921400/6743203](http://stackoverflow.com/a/921400/6743203)

Alternatively refer to: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-download-a-file-from-the-internet/

The renaming should look something like this, without a code example though it's hard to say what exactly you need:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileRenameExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        File oldFileName =new File("path/to/old_file_name.txt");
        File newFileName =new File("path/to/new_file_name.txt");

        if(oldFileName.renameTo(newFileName)){
            System.out.println("Rename succesful");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Rename failed");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("YOUR-PATH/FileName.EXTENSION");
File fNew = new File("YOUR-PATH/NEW-FileName.EXTENSION");
if(f.renameTo(fNew)){
    //do something
}
else{
    //handle exception or throw custom exception
}
```